Cybersource API "Create a Boarding Registration" Works on Developer Portal but Fails in Postman
POST https://apitest.cybersource.com/boarding/v1/registrations
{
  "organizationInformation": {
    "parentOrganizationId": "alpha_001",
    "type": "MERCHANT",
    "configurable": "false",
    "businessInformation": {
      "name": "ArtanStoreTest_123",
      "address": {
        "country": "US",
        "address1": "123456 SandMarket",
        "locality": "ORMOND BEACH",
        "administrativeArea": "FL",
        "postalCode": "32176"
      },
      "websiteUrl": "https://www.StuartWickedEats.com",
      "phoneNumber": "6574567813",
      "businessContact": {
        "firstName": "Stuart",
        "lastName": "Stuart",
        "phoneNumber": "6574567813",
        "email": "svc_email_bt@corpdev.visa.com"
      },
      "merchantCategoryCode": "5999"
    }
  },
  "productInformation": {
    "selectedProducts": {
      "payments": {
        "cardProcessing": {
          "subscriptionInformation": {
            "enabled": true,
            "features": {
              "cardNotPresent": {
                "enabled": true
              }
            }
          },
          "configurationInformation": {
            "configurations": {
              "common": {
                "processors": {
                  "tsys": {
                    "merchantId": "123456789101",
                    "terminalId": "1231",
                    "industryCode": "D (Direct Marketing)",
                    "vitalNumber": "71234567",
                    "merchantBinNumber": "123456",
                    "merchantLocationNumber": "00001",
                    "storeID": "1234",
                    "settlementCurrency": "USD"
                  }
                },
                "merchantCategoryCode": "1234",
                "merchantDescriptorInformation": {
                  "name": "r4ef",
                  "city": "Bellevue",
                  "country": "US",
                  "phone": "4255547845",
                  "state": "WA",
                  "street": "StreetName",
                  "zip": "98007"
                }
              },
              "features": {
                "cardNotPresent": {
                  "visaStraightThroughProcessingOnly": true
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "payerAuthentication": {
          "subscriptionInformation": {
            "enabled": true
          },
          "configurationInformation": {
            "configurations": {
              "cardTypes": {
                "verifiedByVisa": {
                  "currencies": [
                    {
                      "currencyCodes": [
                        "ALL"
                      ],
                      "acquirerId": "469216",
                      "processorMerchantId": "678855"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "virtualTerminal": {
          "subscriptionInformation": {
            "enabled": "true"
          }
        },
        "customerInvoicing": {
          "subscriptionInformation": {
            "enabled": "true"
          }
        },
        "payouts": {
          "subscriptionInformation": {
            "enabled": "true"
          }
        }
      },
      "risk": {
        "fraudManagementEssentials": {
          "subscriptionInformation": {
            "enabled": "true"
          },
          "configurationInformation": {
            "templateId": "10E16B5E-113A-4C14-B527-833EA5C14096"
          }
        }
      },
      "commerceSolutions": {
        "tokenManagement": {
          "subscriptionInformation": {
            "enabled": "true"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I'm trying to use the Cybersource API for the "Create a Boarding Registration" feature, as documented here.
When I test the request on the Cybersource developer portal, it works perfectly. However, when I replicate the same request in Postman, I receive the following error:
{
    "response": {
        "rmsg": "{\"error\":\"UNAUTHORIZED_USER\",\"error_description\":\"UNAUTHORIZED USER\"}"
    }
}

I’m using the same headers as shown in the Cybersource documentation and portal:
 - Authorization: Bearer <Bearer> 
 - Content-Type: application/json
 - v-c-merchant-id: alpha_001
 - Host: apitest.cybersource.com

Has anyone else faced this issue or knows why this might be happening? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
